# Content not being served from STATIC_ROOT

Tags: django

Its my first project in django,so i dont know a lot of things.firstly, i want to serve static files from django STATIC_ROOT, not STATICFILES_DIRS.
this is my project tree:

```html
    src >>
        ...db.sqlite3
        ...manage.py
        ...mainapp (main module) 
              ...__init__.py
              ...settings.py
              ...urls.py
              ...wsgi.py

        ...myapp (django app)
              ...Migrations(Folder)
              ...__init__.py
              ...admin.py
              ...apps.py
              ...models.py
              ...tests.py
              ...views.py
              
         ...accounts (django app)
              ...Migrations(Folder)
              ...__init__.py
              ...admin.py
              ...apps.py
              ...models.py
              ...tests.py
              ...views.py

         ...templates
              ...myapp
                   ...home.html

              ...accounts
                   ...
                   ...
              
         ...static 
              ...myapp 
                  ...css
                      ...bootstrap.css
                      ...home.css
                  ...js
                  ...images
                  
              ...accounts 
                  ...
                  ...
                  ...
                  
          ...static_cdn (STATIC_ROOT)
              ...admin
                  ...
                  ...
                  ...

              ...myapp 
                  ...css
                  ...js
                  ...images
                  
              ...accounts 
                  ...css
                  ...js
                  ...images
```

in settings.py :

```html
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',
    'accounts',
    .....,
    .....,
    .....,
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

.......
.......
.......

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_cdn')
```

in urls.py :

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
.......

from myapp.views import (
        .......,
      .......,
)

from accounts.views import (
      .......,
      .......,
)

urlpatterns = [
      .......,
      .......,
      .......,
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in home.html in templates :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>.......</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/css/bootstrap.css'%}"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/css/home.css'%}"/>
</head>

<body>
  .......
  .......
  .......
</body>

</html>
```

Then i run the command:

```
(clashsite) D:\DjangoSite\clashsite\src>python manage.py collectstatic
```

and following happens:

```
211 static files copied to 'D:\DjangoSite\clashsite\src\static_cdn'.
```

Now,the endpoint,what i want is : *i dont want to serve my static files from 'static' folder in my tree, but from 'static_cdn' folder.more precise,i dont want to serve static files from STATICFILES_DIRS , but from STATIC_ROOT.* But the content are served from only static folder.**if i remove the static folder**,static files are **not served** from static_cdn or STATIC_ROOT.How can i do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ruddra has already explained to you.

to serve your static assets `static_cdn` in production environment you need a web server like `apache` or `nginx` but you can use `xampp` or `wampserver` to serve your `Django` app locally (a mimic production environment as you said) and access it like any web app
served with real domain name (e.g: http://hellodjango.local/)

install `mod_wsgi` for `apache` (https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/) **globally** (meaning **deactivate** first the current virtual environment of your `Django` app)

you need to make some changes to `wsgi.py` file to include `activate_this.py` script.

and then create `vhost` conf file for your app

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName hellodjango.local

    # the root project folder
    DocumentRoot "C:/myapps/hellodjango"
    
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/myapps/hellodjango/src/mainapp/wsgi.py"
    
    <Directory "C:/myapps/hellodjango/src/mainapp">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static_cdn "C:/myapps/hellodjango/src/static_cdn"
    <Directory "C:/myapps/hellodjango/src/static_cdn">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Alias /media_cdn "C:/myapps/hellodjango/src/media_cdn"
    # <Directory "C:/myapps/hellodjango/src/media_cdn">
    #     Require all granted
    # </Directory>

...
</VirtualHost>
```

and don't forget to add `127.0.0.1 hellodjango.local` in `windows` `hosts` file and restart `apache` server.

NB: you can also configure `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` (for file uploads) the same as `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`.

hope this brings you the missing piece of puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

Usage of `STATIC_ROOT` is bit different and it is related to production deployment. What you are seeing here is Django serving contents when you are in `DEBUG=True` mode. It is serving content through [`staticfiles app`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#module-django.contrib.staticfiles).

`STATIC_ROOT` is the directory where static files are stored when you run collect static. But serving from that directory is not what django will do. If you are in production mode(aka `DEBUG=False`), Django will not serve any static contents. Then you need to use a reverse proxy server like NGINX or Apache to serve those static files from `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

More information can be found regarding this on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Comment: But is there no way to to do this??i mean,serve from static root to mimic production environment

Comment: I have already explained how you can do that(by using a separate server like NGINX or Apache), that is what `STATIC_DIR` is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

There are two good answers here, but I think a bit more info will be helpful.  The way that Django is set up, there are 3 important static settings in settings.py (plus the DEBUG setting which is affected):

(1) The URL where the user can access your static files (from the browser) such as http://MySiteOrIP/static/css/main.css and is what is put into the template in replacement of the '% static' plug:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

(2) The absolute path to the directory where Django will both serve your static files from when DEBUG=true and is where the collectstatic command places all of the files it finds:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

(3) The list of directories where you can tell Django to look for additional static files in additional locations to the normal includes:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ([
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
])
```

I have my settings.py set up to accept the setting for DEBUG from the OS but in any case, with nginx (my preferred server) I set up the redirect to serve all static contact from the directory specified in the STATIC_ROOT by adding a relevant section to the config file in /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite:

```
# Django project's static files
location /static/ {
    alias /home/django/django_project/assets/;
}
```

If you have screwed it up and need it fixed, you can set all this up and delete the files in the collected folder before they are collected again by adding "--clear' to the end of the collectstatic command.  I have found it best to just reboot after these large modifications.

Hope that helps someone!